# Independence of increasing sequence of events

Tags: probability, independence

Let $A$, $B$, $A_1$, $A_2$, ... be events. Suppose that for each k, we have $A_k \subseteq  A_{k+1}$, and that $A_k$ is independent of $B$, $\forall k \geq 1$. If $A = \bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} A_{k}$, then show that $B$ is independent of $A$.

My attempt:

$A_n \rightarrow A$, so $A = \bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} A_{k} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} A_n$

$P(A \cap B) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(A_n \cap B)= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(A_n)P(B)$ (by independence of $A_n$ and $B$)

$ = P(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} A_n)P(B) = P(A)P(B)$

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Thanks for conforming @geetha290krm

Comment: How do you know $P(A\cap B)=\lim_{n\to\infty}P(A_n\cap B)$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson .Sequence of events ($A_n \cap B$) are monotonically increasing as ($A_n$) are increasing. By continuity of probability we've $P(A \cap B) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(A_n \cap B)$.